# jdbc batch insert returning extremely slow in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to do batch insert with the `returning` clause with `jdbc`, it executes very slow, for ~1k entry, takes about 20-30s(exactly the `ps.executeBatch()` takes this long).

Below is the code:

```
      String[] returningColumns = ...;
      
      try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO map_element (bbox,content,is_committed,last_updated_at,map_id,tags,version) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", returningColumns)) {
        for (int instance_i = 0; instance_i < newInstances.size(); ++instance_i) {
          ps.clearParameters();
          ps.addXXX...
          ps.addBatch();
        }

        LOGGER.warnf("%d: insert batch", System.currentTimeMillis());
        int[] ret = ps.executeBatch();
        LOGGER.warnf("%d: insert batch done", System.currentTimeMillis());

        // retrieve generated fields
        if (!missingFields.isEmpty()) {
          ResultSet returningVals = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
          int returnCount = 0;
          while (returningVals.next()) {
            fillMissingFields(newInstances.get(returnCount), missingFields, returningVals);
            ++returnCount;
          }
        }
        return newInstances;
      }
```

Several interesting experiment and observations:

- 1. this issue only happens in some postgres instance(the connection URL is similar, no extra attributes)

  - this issue happens in the postgres instance on AWS, version `PostgreSQL 12.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit`
  - my local postgres is fine, batch insert takes ~500ms.  version `PostgreSQL 13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-4.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit`

Of course the latency might be a issue since local server is running on the same machine as my local postgres, but I don't think the different would be that much.

- 2. Executing pure String concatenated plain statement is extremely fast, in both postgres instances.
- 3. if I remove the `returning` logic, it runs very fast, in both postgres instances.
- 4. I tried to append plain returning clause instead of using `preparedStatemet(sql, returningColumns)`, doesn't help
- 5. the returning columns are not large, mostly some integer id/ timestamp
- 6. tried adding `?rewriteBatchedStatements=true` attribute to the url, no luck
- 7. after enabling the trace log in jdbc, I found this warning `Couldn't estimate result size or result size unbounded, disabling batching for this query.` only when I use that `returning` clause

I believe it has something to do with the returning clause in `PreparedStatement`. Pls give some hints to help me further investigate this issue.

BTW my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE feature.map_element (
  map_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES feature.map(map_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  element_id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  version BIGINT NOT NULL,
  tags VARCHAR [] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}',
  bbox public.geometry NOT NULL,
  content BYTEA NOT NULL,
  patch_id BIGINT,
  state_id INTEGER,
  assignee VARCHAR,
  last_updated_at BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT cur_ts_ms(),
  is_committed BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  is_active BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  msg VARCHAR,
  PRIMARY KEY (map_id, element_id, version)
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS map_element_patch_id_idx ON feature.map_element (patch_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS map_element_bbox_GIST_idx ON feature.map_element USING GIST(bbox);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS map_element_tags_GIN_idx ON feature.map_element USING GIN(tags);
```

Comment: "Of course the latency might be a issue since local server is running on the same machine as my local postgres, but I don't think the different would be that much."  Why not?  I think the difference *would* be that much.  And it shows up exactly when expected, when the batching doesn't actually batch.

Comment: @jjanes good point...I just tried different batch size and the execution time is almost linear. Thanks for the point and I think I have to look into why the batching is diabled....